# Firebase ios auth credentials after app transfer

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

What will happen to firebase login credentials after we transfer our app to a different developer account?

Will our app lose access to login credentials since they are stored in Keychain?

In our app, we use a "custom authentication system".

- We don't require emails or passwords from our users while signing in.
- Instead, we call a cloud function that creates a user and sends an auth token back to the clients.
- In client app, we sign in our users with `Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: token)`

How can we overcome this problem without losing users' login credentials in our app if we'll lose that credentials? What precautions can we take before the transfer?

Thanks.

Comment: Uptill now what i have read you will lose the users, reason being you will have to create a new app with a new bundle id.

Comment: Hey, I just transferred an app, and I hit this situation, and Apple says they can't help me, I only can transfer back to my old account to solve the issue... What did you en up doing? Thanks!